# Rails 3 Inflection Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold, inflector

I'm having a problem with generating scaffold for a Regatta. When I run

```
rails g scaffold Regatta name:string start_date:datetime
```

I get a model named regattum and a controller called regatta_controller (instead of regattas_controller)

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20110609221608_create_regatta.rb
  create    app/models/regattum.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/unit/regattum_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/regatta.yml
   route  resources :regatta
  invoke  scaffold_controller
  create    app/controllers/regatta_controller.rb
  invoke    erb
  create      app/views/regatta
  create      app/views/regatta/index.html.erb
  create      app/views/regatta/edit.html.erb
  create      app/views/regatta/show.html.erb
  create      app/views/regatta/new.html.erb
  create      app/views/regatta/_form.html.erb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/functional/regatta_controller_test.rb
  invoke    helper
  create      app/helpers/regatta_helper.rb
  invoke      test_unit
  create        test/unit/helpers/regatta_helper_test.rb
  invoke  stylesheets
```

identical    public/stylesheets/scaffold.css

Obviously this is an inflection problem, but whenever I modify /config/initializers/inflections.rb I get an error saying:

```
The name 'Regatta' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.
```

I have tried everything I can think of to make it work, but I keep getting an error. Any advice on a solution or a workaround would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update**

Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'regatta', 'regattas'
end
```

That didn't change anything so I tried a few of the options below, among others,in varying combinations to no avail:

```
 inflect.plural 'regatta', 'regattas'
  inflect.singular 'regattas', 'regatta'
  inflect.singular 'regatta', 'regatta'
```

---

**Update 2**

Here is the code I used in inflections.rb once I figured out what I was doing wrong:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'regatta', 'regattas'
  inflect.singular 'regatta', 'regatta'
  inflect.singular 'regattas', 'regatta'
end
```

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future!

Comment: How are you modifying the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the error message saying that `Regatta` is already in use in your application (it's obviously not reserved by Rails), I'm guessing the `Regattum` model is still in place.

I'd recommend destroying the scaffold and trying again. It sounds like, once a word is already defined in the application, Rails has a built-in protection against changing the inflection. So, this error being thrown is to protect against unexpected behavior in this very situation.

Comment: I destroyed the scaffold -- so there are no models, controllers or views -- and still no luck with the inflector. I also never did `rake db:migrate` so there are no database tables either. I'm pulling my hair out over this one.

Comment: You were right. I called my application regatta, and that was obviously throwing it off. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 9):

I recognize this post is old, but I thought I would contribute my findings as well.

I have been integrating rpsec and cucumber into my application after much development (yes; naughty, naughty).  I wanted to generate the rspec stubs for my models and get my application unit tested.  I am usually able to move an associated migration out of db/migrate/ and run 'bundle exec rails g  ' to regenerate the scaffolds and in this case, the rspec stubs.  Not this time.

<terminal>

```
bundle exec rails g scaffold User email:string ... 
      updated_at:datetime roles_mask:integer --trace

      invoke  active_record

The name 'User' is either already used in your application 
      or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative 
      and run this generator again.
```

My problem was resolved by temporarily commenting out the 'devise_for' line in my 'config/routes.rb' file

config/routes.rb

```
#devise_for :users
```

Bingo.  And this isn't the only time that Devise has surprised me with 'black magic' that is not readily apparent.  I un-commented the line once my rspec stubs were generated, of course.  Now it's off to writing my unit tests!

Comment: Over two years later and still relevant. This helped me out as well, thank you.